# How to transform image over object

Tags: php

Example: http://gyazo.com/745e6912db5bf2c1dd05a7a7537bfca4.png

I wanna put image over object... so that it looks like a native picture over the object. Could you give key words of these image manipulation process that i can google it ;)

Answer (score -1):

it's not PHP, but client-side programming you want to look into. Try CSS z-index properties.